# mysql select records like in facebook's feed

Tags: mysql, sql

I thing this is a quite challenging question..

I have a "USERS" table:

```
ID | name
```

I have a LOCATIONS table where I store the users location:

```
USERID | location
```

I have a USERS_INTERESTS table:

```
USERID | interests (comma-separated IDs of the INTERESTS table )
```

INTERESTS:

```
interest_ID | interest_name
```

POSTS_

```
post_ID | userPosting | description | post_datetime
```

I now need to create something like Facebook's feed, where I select the posts of users most similar to me, taking into consideration the user's location and interests.

I should select the last 10 posts insert by users "similar" to me (in my location and/or with the most interests in common with mines).

Moreover, this should be done with some kind of "priority":

- I select posts of users in my location with my interests
- if there are too few records, I include posts of users in my same location and with SOME interests in common
- If not enough, I include posts of users in my location.

Not enough, this should be done on a time-basis: I select the 10 most relevant posts every 20 minutes.

I know it's very complicated, hope someone can point me in the right direction. thank you

Comment: do you have any query to work with?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: @KayNelson
I don't have a query jet, I think comparing users location part is quite easy. I have problems comparing users interests, since they are two comma-separated ids and I need to give priority to users with the mosts values in common. 
I have NO IDEA about how to perform a time-based selection (the 10 most relevant posts every 20 minutes). Any help greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's several parts to this question and most need rethinking.

First there's the "similar" part. There's pretty much a single way to do that in MySQL and that's if one location is part of another, like "York" is part of "New York", then you can find that "New York" is similar to "York". Now if you had some other data about location, like geological coordinates or a general area like a district or state then you could define similarity as "towns in the same state".

Similarity with interests could be simpler - you can cound how many interests match between two people. To make this easier you should organize your interests table into long format, meaning the table structure would be like:

```
USERID_1 | INTEREST_1
USERID_1 | INTEREST_2
etc
```

As for building the actual query - you should approach it step by step.

1) lets assume we try to generate the result for the current user with user ID `userID`. Since the connection is through location and interests we should first query the current users location and interests.

2) take the current users location and query users who have similar locations based on however you decide to define "similar". If you manage to define a similarity metric, then query it as well. I mean something like "being in same state is more similar than being on same continent". Save the users you find this way.

3) do the same with current users interests and save the found users.

4) merge the two lists, possibly according to similarity metrics and save the resulting list of users.

5) query the posts according to this list, pick 10 of those. Save those into a new table along with current users id a timestamp. Next time you start this process first check the new table to see if 20 minutes has passed since this list was generated for current user - if it has then generate a new one, if not then use the list in table.

It's actually not as complicated as it sounds :)